# Can't mount NAS

Tags: mount, fstab

I'm running Debian on BBB. I'm trying to mount NAS WD My Book Live.
my `fstab` file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Auto generated by: beaglebone-black-eMMC-flasher.sh
#
UUID=d91f9fd0-cffe-40bb-88bc-2844bf27b2cd  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1
UUID=485D-6D99  /boot/uboot  auto  defaults  0  0
debugfs         /sys/kernel/debug  debugfs  defaults          0  0
//10.0.0.6/Music/Music /mnt/music cifs defaults,username=any,password=admin 0 0
```

when I use `mount _a`

I get an error message

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: Try `//10.0.0.6/Music /mnt/music cifs defaults,username=any,password=admin 0 0`

Comment: Thanks, I already tried and it did not work

Comment: `smbclient -L //10.0.0.6`. Lower/Uppercase might be the problem.

Comment: I tried using lower case music but the result is the same

Comment: Maybe its MUsic??

Comment: It's definitely Music

Answer (score 1):

Try manual mounting,

```
mount –t cifs \\10.0.0.6\Music\Music\ /mnt/music –o username=any password:
```

Also try to alter the "/" as "\" for network path in fstab file and then check the mount

```
\\10.0.0.6\Music\Music\ /mnt/music cifs defaults,username=any,password=admin 0 0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I got some progress with manual mounting but I'm getting now: Couldn't chdir to username=any,password=admin: No such file or directory

Comment: Don't give the password while trying manual mount ..use the command as stated in the answer...It will prompt for the password and then you can type your password....Now its considering whole "username=any,password=admin" as a file..

Comment: This command is not recognizable:                   root@beaglebone:~# mount -t cifs \\10.0.0.6\Music\Music\ /mnt/o username=any password:
Usage: mount -V                 : print version
       mount -h                 : print this help
       mount                    : list mounted filesystems
       mount -l                 : idem, including volume labels
So far the informational part. Next the mounting.
The command is `mount [-t fstype] something somewhere'.
Details found in /etc/fstab may be omitted.